# Initilaize UiWebView with Songkick widget code

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I would like to initialize a UIWebView with the following html/javascript code:

```
<a class="songkick-widget" href="http://www.songkick.com/artists/6833354" data-theme="light" data-font-color="#4F4640" data-background-color="#FDFDFD">Dates</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//widget.songkick.com/widget.js"></script>
```

It's a widget obtained from songkick. Do let me know if i need additional html (e.g. `<body></body>` etc.).

Please let me know how I can initialize the UIWebView to display this widget.

Thanks,
Jas

Answer (score 0):

You can put it inside a NSString

and call the

```
[webView loadHTMLString: htmlString baseURL: nil];
```